# How to keep objects in the same position relative to their parent?

Tags: c#, mathematics, sprites, windows-forms

I'm writing a simple game in C# and i'm having some difficulty to calculate the local position of a sprite.

What i'm aiming to achieve:

- *Calculate the sprite* "**local position**" relative to the parent.
- *When the parent sprite position is changed*, **the children sprite should be aways *following the parent* while keeping its relative position**.

Example:

Lets assume i have a parent sprite at world position (4, 4) and a children sprite at local position (2, 2), if the parent sprite world position moves to (5, 5), his children local position should be at (3, 3).

Below is a example code of what i'm trying to make.
Lets assume the parent sprite moved and called **UpdateChildrenPositions** with his new position, what should the **local** and **world** positions of his childrens be?

```
public class Sprite
{
    public Sprite parent;
    public List<Sprite> childrens;
    
    public Point world_position;
    public Point local_position;
    
    public void UpdateChildrenPositions(Point new_position)
    {
        // What should these numbers contain?
        this.world_position = ???
        this.local_position = ???
    }
}
```

Could someone provide a **direct** answer with the math to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent moving, by definition, does *not* change the local position. So you only need to change the world position, using the parent's world position and the *unchanged* local position as the source of truth.

```
public void UpdateWorldPositionUsingParent() {
    world_position = parent.world_position + local_position;

    // TODO: update positions of any children of this object
    // (grandchildren of our parent).
}
```

When you want to change the position of an object relative to its parent, you can adjust the world position and local position together:

```
public void SetPosition(Point newWorldPosition) {
    world_position = newWorldPosition;
    local_position = newWorldPosition - parent.world_position;

     // TODO: update positions of any children of this object
    // (grandchildren of our parent).
}
```

You can also use a dirty flag to mark objects whose world position is out of date, and update it lazily down the child hierarchy only when needed.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I'll do some testings and see if it works in my project, i'll come back later and report.

Comment: I think this is working but i'm having other problems, tomorrow i'll probably post another question, thanks for the answer.