# Move sprite in relation to parent?

Tags: c#, mathematics

I'm writing a simple game in C# and i'm having some difficulty to calculate the local position of a sprite.

What i'm aiming to achieve:

- *Calculate the sprite* "**local position**" relative to the parent.
- *When the parent sprite position is changed*, **the children sprite should be aways *following the parent* while keeping its relative position**.

Example:

Lets assume i have a parent sprite at world position (4, 4) and a children sprite at local position (2, 2), if the parent sprite world position moves to (5, 5), his children local position should be at (3, 3).

Below is a example code of what i'm trying to make.
Lets assume the parent of this sprite moved and UpdateChildren was called:

```
public class Sprite
{
    public Sprite parent;
    public Point world_position;
    public Point local_position;
    
    public void UpdateChildren(Point new_position)
    {
        // What should these numbers contain?
        this.world_position = ???
        this.local_position = ???
    }
}
```

Could someone provide a **direct** answer with the math to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep objects in the same position relative to their parent?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/195411/how-to-keep-objects-in-the-same-position-relative-to-their-parent)

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "local position (2, 2)"? In the usual terminology, the child's local position does not change when the parent moves, but instead is applied to the parent's changed world position to end up with a new *world* position for the child.

Comment: Hi, i don't understand much about how this works yet but what i want to do is make the children sprite follow the parent while keeping its relative position. Could you provide a answer with the math to do this?

Comment: It looks like this was meant to be an edit to your previous question. Please edit your existing question so it can be re-opened, rather than posting a duplicate.

Comment: You are right, i edited the last post. Could you allow posting asnwers to it again?